# Can i get lead gen data at linked in using webhooks URL and C# likd facebook?

Tags: api, dynamics-crm, linkedin-api, webhooks

i have an application in linked in and have page on it and Campaign manager, i want to send leads data automatically to Microsoft Dynamics CRM without downloading the leads,i want to make this cycle dynamics.
i do not know where can i add My Webhooks URL to can send leads information to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your req, you have an external system (non crm) and from this system you wish to get information from crm and perform some operation in crm.

I would suggest you go with Dynamics 365 webpi.
Create Application user in Azure AD and give proper rights, Then create this user in CRM and you are good to go.
You have an user dedicated to perform Interface tasks. You do not need unnecessary webhooks or other technologies.

https://www.dynamicsforcrm.com/using-postman-with-dyanmics-365-web-api/

[https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminthefield/posts/setup-postman-to-use-web-api-for-dynamics-365-ce-online-#:~:text=Postman%20is%20a%20popular%20tool,to%20be%20permitted%20by%20AAD](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminthefield/posts/setup-postman-to-use-web-api-for-dynamics-365-ce-online-#:%7E:text=Postman%20is%20a%20popular%20tool,to%20be%20permitted%20by%20AAD).

https://carldesouza.com/calling-the-power-apps-and-dynamics-365-web-api-from-the-postman-windows-client/

https://medium.com/capgemini-microsoft-team/dynamics-365-application-users-no-additional-license-required-and-no-limit-on-quantity-4bdc49f8ce2d

Comment: I want to get the data from linked lead gen Form using custom API, not from CRM

Comment: yes even then you have to use Dynamics 365 webapi to push data to crm