# LinkedIn: API to get leads by URN?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm integrating against LinkedIn's webhook to get leads automatically, when an ad form is filled out. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/lead-gen/ads-leadgen#lead-notification-webhooks) for the lead notification webhook show the response will contain a `adFormResponseUrn`, but the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/lead-gen/ads-leadgen#fetching-ad-form-responses) to list leads only takes a time- / date-range. I could periodically poll that API, and filter out leads we've already processed, but would prefer to get leads by webhook. **What API can get leads with those URNs?**

I've tried searching the rest of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin), LinkedIn's [help section](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin), the [answers section](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers) of Microsoft's docs. The [only question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527838/can-i-get-lead-gen-data-at-linked-in-using-webhooks-url-and-c-sharp-likd-faceboo) I can find here in Stack Overflow, is for a pre-built integration, not using the webhooks and APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API to get leads by ID is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/lead-gen/ads-leadgen?tabs=http#fetching-ad-form-responses), and webhooks may be enabled by [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/lead-gen/ads-leadgen?tabs=http#lead-notification-webhooks).

*(There's new docs added since I asked this question.)*